# Filtering transaction level data

Tags: r, dplyr

I am dealing with a data frame containing the transaction level data. It contains two fields, `bill_id` and `product`.

The data represents products purchased at a bill level, and a particular `bill_id` gets repeated as many times as the number of products purchased in that bill. For example, if 5 items have been purchased in bill_id 12345, the data for this bill will be like this:

```
bill_id product
  12345       A
  12345       B
  12345       C
  12345       D
  12345       E
```

My objective is to filter out data of all bills containing a certain product.

Following is an example of how I am performing this task currently:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

# Sample data
dat <- data.frame(bill_id = sample(1:500, size = 1000, replace = TRUE),
                  product = sample(LETTERS, size = 1000, replace = 
                  TRUE),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
       arrange(bill_id, product)

# vector of bill_ids of product A
bills_productA <- dat %>% 
                  filter(product == "A") %>% 
                  pull(bill_id) %>% 
                  unique()

# data for bill_ids in vector bills_productA
dat_subset <- dat %>%
              filter(bill_id %in% bills_productA)
```

This leads to the creation of an intermediary vector of bill_ids (`bills_productA`) and a two-step filtering process (first find ids of bills containing the product, and then find all transactions of these bills).

Is there a more efficient way of performing this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a data.table approach:

**preparation**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
```

**actual code**

```
dat[ bill_id %in% dat[ product == "A",][[1]], ]
```

**output**

```
#    bill_id product
# 1:      14       A
# 2:      14       I
# 3:      19       A
# 4:      19       W
# 5:      22       A
# ---                
# 130:     478       A
# 131:     478       V
# 132:     478       Z
# 133:     494       A
# 134:     494       J
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `filter` the `bill_id` by directly subsetting it

```
library(dplyr)
dat_subset1 <- dat %>% filter(bill_id %in% unique(bill_id[product == "A"]))

identical(dat_subset, dat_subset1) 
#[1] TRUE
```

This would also work without `unique` in it but better to keep the list short.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation:

```
library(dplyr)
dat_subset2 <- semi_join(dat, filter(dat, product == "A") %>% select(bill_id))

> identical(dat_subset, dat_subset2) 
[1] TRUE
```